# Creating mutually inclusive positional arguments with argparse

Tags: python, argparse

I'm trying to build a command line interface with Python's argparse module. I want two positional arguments where one depends on the other (mutually inclusive). Here is what I want:

```
prog [arg1 [arg2]]
```

Here's what I have so far:

```
prog [arg1] [arg2]
```

Which is produced by:

```
parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
parser.add_argument('arg1', nargs='?')
parser.add_argument('arg2', nargs='?')
```

How do I get from there to having a mutually inclusive arg2?

Comment: Take a look at https://github.com/docopt/docopt

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Module `argparse` doesn't have options for creating mutually inclusive arguments.
However it's simple to write it by yourself.
Start with adding both arguments as optional:

```
parser.add_argument('arg1', nargs='?')
parser.add_argument('arg2', nargs='?')
```

After parsing arguments check if `arg1` is set and `arg2` is not:

```
args = parser.parse_args()
if args.arg1 and not args.arg2:
```

(this may be more tricky if you change default value from `None` for not used arguments to something different)

Then use `parser.error()` function to display normal `argparse` error message:

```
parser.error('the following arguments are required: arg2')
```

Finally change *usage:* message to show that `arg2` depends on `arg1`:

```
parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(usage='%(prog)s [arg1 [arg2]]')
```

A complete script:

```
import argparse

parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(usage='%(prog)s [arg1 [arg2]]')
parser.add_argument('arg1', nargs='?')
parser.add_argument('arg2', nargs='?')

args = parser.parse_args()

if args.arg1 and not args.arg2:
    parser.error('the following arguments are required: arg2')
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do something similar to this using `sub_parsers`.

Here are the docs and examples:

http://docs.python.org/2/library/argparse.html#sub-commands

Comment: Unfortunately, this wouldn't work, because arg1 needs to be dynamic. Sub-commands are fixed strings. For example, prog multiarg arg1 arg2, where multiarg is the fixed command string. Also, even after adding a sub-command you would end up with the same situation.