# Python argparse : How can I make an argument and a group of argument mutually exclusive?

Tags: python-3.x, command-line-interface, argparse

I have 4 different arguments, let's call them A, B, C and D

I would like A to be exclusive from B, C and D but B, C and D should always be called together

In the argparse documentation I found the [add_mutually_exclusive_group](https://docs.python.org/3/library/argparse.html#mutual-exclusion) method but it would make my arguments A, B, C and D all exclusive from one another

How can I require my argument to by either `[A] or [B and C and D]` ?

Comment: Unfortunately, argparse doesn't have a way to do mutually *inclusive* arguments (e.g. `[B and C and D]`), so you will have to resort to checking your arguments manually after parsing, similar to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15935092/creating-mutually-inclusive-positional-arguments-with-argparse) on a similar prior question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since it seems like I cannot use argparse directly with the configuration I wanted to get, here is how I proceeded with Python :

```
import argparse
import sys

parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(description="Test program")
parser.add_argument('-a', type=str, help="arg A")
parser.add_argument('-b', type=str, help="arg B")
parser.add_argument('-c', type=str, help="arg C")
parser.add_argument('-d', type=str, help="arg D")
args = parser.parse_args(sys.argv[1:])

if args.a is None and args.b is None and args.c is None and args.d is None:
    print("Error : at least one argument is required")
    exit(1)
if args.a:
    if args.b or args.c or args.d:
        print("Error argument a cannot be used with arguments b, c and d")
        exit(1)
    print("scenario with argument a")
else:
    if args.b is None or args.c is None or args.d is None:
        print("when not using argument a, arguments b, c and d must all be set")
        exit(1)
    print("scenario with arguments b, c and d")
```

This covers all of the mentioned use cases